# Splitting list by Date property in C# or using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a `List<Event>` and an `Event` has a `Date` property.  I'm currently binding this list to an `asp:repeater` which is fine and results in a list of event titles like this:

event 1
event 2
event 3
event 4
event 5

However, now I wish to add some kind of separator to my list between events occurring on different days so that my list looks like:

**Tuesday, May 10, 2011**
event 1
event 2
**Wednesday, May 11, 2011**
event 3
**Thursday, May 12, 2011**
event 4
event 5

Can anyone recommend a good way to do this.  I'm happy to manipulate my list server-side or to bind my list and then add the separators client-side with jQuery.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have nested `asp:repeater` with a the query grouped by Event Date and the outer repeater just displaying the Date and the inner repeater showing the events for that group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by date server side using Linq's [GroupBy](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/09/28/9836.aspx)

```
class Event
{
    public DateTime EventDate;
    public string EventName;
}

List<Event> events = GetEvents();

var grouped = events.GroupBy(e => e.EventDate.Date).OrderBy(g => g.Key);

foreach (var grouping in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grouping.Key); // <-- this is the date

    foreach (Event e in grouping) // <-- this is the list of events
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.EventName); 
    }
}
```

`GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, so in this case you are returning `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Event>>`

Comment: +1 - I used this and the nested repeaters in Matias Fidemraizer's answer to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use nested repeaters - in this case you'll need two of them -.

Parent repeater render dates and nested one items for parent item's date.

It's all about setting Repeaters' data source in another way than current one and play with Repeater.ItemDataBound event.

Comment: +1 - I used this and the grouping in fearofawhackplanet's answer to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the events by day and use that key as a header of the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
List date = (From Event n in yourEventList
                      select new {n.Date}).ToList().Distinct();

foreach (DateTime dateA in date)
{
//add to the Date and then add the events does match with the date.
}
```